# If-then-else condition for print argument of a command

Tags: errors, xifthen

I am a beginner in latex and I've some problem on implementing an 'if-then-else' condition in LaTEX. In particular, I've tried to print an argumen when it is passed in the command \newenvironment and print nothing when is not passed.

I've obtaneid this result when the argument is passed (Note that the argument is print twice. This is not desired.):

[image]

When the argument is not passed, the brackets still remain, but without text inside. The compiler give the error `

```
Undefined control sequence. \begin{exercise}{}
```

The entire part of code interessed by the problem is the following.

```
\newenvironment{exercise}[1]% environment name{
\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
\refstepcounter{exercise}%

\textbf{Esercizio \theexercise \IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{ (#1)}}%

\begin{itshape}%
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}%
    \noindent\ignorespaces
}%
{% end code
\end{itshape}%
\par\vspace{\baselineskip}%
\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}
```

I hope I've been sufficiently clear. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Where did you get this kind of non-working code? `\IfNoValue` is a command from `xparse`, which is not possible to use within `\newenvironment`.

Comment: also `\noindent` will not give an error but it will produce entirely spurious results here. However it is hard to test your code if you only post a fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing your use of syntax. `\IfNoValueTF` forms part of the [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse) syntax and require you to build the environment using `\NewDocumentEnvironment` with an `o`ptional argument:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{exercise}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise}{o}
  {% \begin code
   \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
   \refstepcounter{exercise}%
   \textbf{Esercizio \theexercise \IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{ (#1)}}%
   \par\nobreak\vspace{\baselineskip}%
   \itshape\noindent\ignorespaces
  }%
  {% end code
   \par\vspace{\baselineskip}%
   \ignorespacesafterend
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
This is an exercise
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[abc]
This is another exercise
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can you remove the italic style from the text of the 'exercise'?

Comment: @Alberto: Italics is introduced with `\itshape`. Remove it if you don't want it.